# How to prove that a $n\times n$ matrix has distinct eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to solve the following question:

> Let A be an $n \times n$ matrix, and suppose that the only eigenvalues of $A$ are $0,$ $1,$ and $2.$
> (a) Prove that $\dim E_1(A) + \dim E_2(A) \leq \operatorname{rank} A.$
> Where $E_1$ and $E_2$ is the eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalues $1$ and $2$ respectively.

I have found a way to prove this if all of the eigenvalues are distinct, because then the geometric multiplicity must be 1 for each of them, and thus the dimension there must be less than or equal to Rank(A). That's the approach I've taken to the problem so far. My assumption of the eigenvalues being distinct also allows for an easy proof that A is diagonalizable.

However, I have no way to prove my assumption, given the information in the question, that each of the eigenvalues is actually distinct. I am lost on how I would prove that, if I even can. There must be a way, because I don't really see another approach to showing that dim E1(A) + dim E2(A) ≤ rank A

Comment: all this is asking is for you to show that the geometric multiplicities of eigenvalues are bounded above by algebraic multiplicities and that the total number of non-zero roots to $A$'s characteristic polynomial is a lower bound for its rank (hint: assume $A$ is upper triangular and count pivots)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $\mathcal B_1$ denote a basis of $E_1(A)$ and $\mathcal B_2$ a basis of $E_2(A)$. Let $\mathcal R(A)$ denote the range (AKA column-space of $A$). Keeping in mind that ${\rm rank}(A) = \dim \mathcal R(A)$, show that $\mathcal B_1 \cup \mathcal B_2$ is a linearly independent subset of $\mathcal R(A)$. Because the number of elements in $\mathcal B_1 \cup \mathcal B_2$ is equal to $\dim E_1(A) + \dim E_2(A)$, the conclusion follows.

Comment: I think there's a typo, do you mean "show that ... linearly independent subset of $\mathcal{R}(A)$" (instead of $\mathcal{A}$)?

Comment: @YiFan Good catch, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we're working over the base field $k$, so that in particular we want to understand the eigenbehavior of some linear map $A\colon k^{n}\to k^{n}$. Observe that for each $\lambda\in k$, $$E_{\lambda,A} = \ker\left(A-\lambda\right) \subseteq k^{n},$$ where $E_{\lambda,A}$ is the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$ and $A-\lambda$ is a fruitful shorthand for $A-\lambda I_{n}$. For $\Lambda=\left(\lambda_{i}\in k\right)_{i=0}^{h-1}$ a list of $h$ elements of $k$, there is a canonical (linear) map $$\tau_{\Lambda}\colon\ \bigoplus_{i=0}^{h-1} E_{\lambda_{i},A}\ \to\ k^{n}.$$ If the entries of $\Lambda$ are distinct, then this map is injective, as for all $j\in\left\{0,\dots,h-1\right\}$, \begin{align*}\tau_{\Lambda}\left(\left(v_{i}\in E_{\lambda_{i},A}\right)_{i=0}^{h-1}\right) = 0\ :&\iff\ \sum_{i=0}^{h-1} v_{i}=0\\ &\implies\ \left(\prod_{i=0,\ i\neq j}^{h-1}\left(A-\lambda_{i}\right)\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{h-1} v_{i}\right)=0\\ &\implies\ \left(\prod_{i=0,\ i\neq j}^{h-1}\left(\lambda_{j}-\lambda_{i}\right)\right)v_{j}=0\\ &\implies\ v_{j}=0.\end{align*} (Here we use the fact that if $v_{j}\in E_{\lambda_{j},A}$ then $\left(A-\lambda_{i}\right)v_{j}=\left(\lambda_{j}-\lambda_{i}\right)v_{j}$ and that that if the entries of $\Lambda$ are distinct, then $\prod_{i=0,\ i\neq j}^{h-1}\left(\lambda_{j}-\lambda_{i}\right)\neq 0$.) Thus for $\Lambda=\left(\lambda_{i}\right)_{i=0}^{h-1}$ a list of $h$ distinct eigenvalues of $A$, we have that $$\sum_{i=0}^{h-1}\dim\left(E_{\lambda_{i},A}\right)\ =\ \dim\left(\bigoplus_{i=0}^{h-1} E_{\lambda_{i},A}\right)\ \leq\ n.$$ Applying this to the case at hand and assuming that $k$ is not of characteristic $2$ (in which case the claim fails), $$\dim\left(E_{1,A}\right)+\dim\left(E_{2,A}\right)\ \leq\ n-\underbrace{\dim\left(E_{0,A}\right)}_{=\dim\left(\ker\left(A\right)\right)}\ =\ \text{rank}\left(A\right)$$ (the last equality by rank-nullity), as desired.